# Restricted sumsets - the origins?

Tags: reference-request, ho.history-overview, terminology, additive-combinatorics, sumsets

The *sumset* of the subsets $A$ and $B$ of an additively written group is defined by $A+B:=\{a+b\colon a\in A,\ b\in B\}$. The basic idea to add sets has been around since Cauchy at least.

Erdős and Heilbronn considered a variation where equal summands are excluded from consideration. This version of set addition was further generalized to consider *restricted sumsets* where the sums allowed are taken "along the edges of a graph": that is, given a set $E\subseteq A\times B$, we let $A\stackrel{E}{+}B:=\{a+b\colon a\in A,\ b\in B,\ (a,b)\in E\}$. Perhaps, the most famous result where restricted sumsets play a central role is the Balog-Szemerédi-Gowers theorem.

I am interested in the historical component of the story.

- When and where restricted sumsets of a general form (that is, the addition of sets along a graph) were introduced?
- Who has coined the name "restricted sumset"?
- Where does the notation $A\stackrel{E}{+}B$ originate from?

Comment: In this preprint, https://arxiv.org/pdf/0905.0135.pdf, they seem to say that the answer to your first question is the original sum-product paper of Erdős–Szemerédi ("On sums and products of integers"). I believe equation (3) in the Erdős–Szemerédi paper is what they mean. Erdős–Szemerédi do not use either the terminology restricted sumset, or the sumset notation, however.

Comment: Here's a link to the Erdős–Szemerédi paper: https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.210.6957&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: I suppose a related question (whose answer I would guess you know already) is who introduced the word sumset and the notation $A+B$ for sumsets. That would give a lower bound for the year for your other two questions that might make it easier to search for the answer.